Localized Mandatory Field Not Displaying Asterisk (*) in Pimcore 11.4.3
I am using Pimcore 11.4.3 and have created a class with a localized field called name. I marked the name field as mandatory, but the expected asterisk (*) indicating the mandatory status does not appear in the data object.
However, when using a downgraded version, such as Pimcore 11.1.1, the mandatory field correctly displays the name*.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a class in Pimcore 11.4.3 with a localized field named name.
Mark the name field as mandatory. Open the data object and check if
the name* is displayed. Expected Behavior: The name field should
display an asterisk (name*) in the data object to indicate that it is
a mandatory field.

Actual Behavior:
The name* is not displayed in the data object in Pimcore 11.4.3, but it works as expected in Pimcore 11.1.1.
Environment Details:
Pimcore Version: 11.4.3 (Issue present)
Pimcore Version: 11.1.1 (Working correctly)
PHP Version: [8.1.2]
Database: [8.1]
Question:
Is this a known issue or a change in how mandatory fields are displayed in Pimcore 11.4.3?
Are there any configurations or workarounds to fix this?

It would be helpful to see some of the code you're working with. My guess is that the asterisk is in the string being translated and is lost during the translation. A simple solution may be to put the output of the translation in the field label and then append the asterisk
